# Need to display values comma values in csv file using shell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have merged two configuration files using paste command- paste -d, file1 file2 > file.csv,But i have two values in the file1,file2 which have values like a=b,c and a=b,c,d In the csv file c and d are being displayed in a separate field,Need help in fixing it out so that in a single field a=b,c should be displayed.Tried methods like awk '{gsub(/,/,"")};1' file1 > file.csv but it displayed like a=bc instead of a=b,c
Thanks in advance!!

Tried methods like awk '{gsub(/,/,"")};1' file1 > file.csv but it displayed like a=bc instead of a=b,c
and tried to escape comma /, but none worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without example file1 and file2 I hope I give an answer to your real problem. I give three solutions, you can change a solution to match your requirements.
Put double quotes around the complete lines before the `paste` with `<(subcommand)`

```
paste -d, <(sed 's/.*/"&"/' file1) <(sed 's/.*/"&"/' file2)
```

Use a special character in the `paste` and repair when `paste` is finished.

```
paste -d'\r' file1 file2 | sed -r 's/([^\r]*)\r(.*)/"\1","\2"/'
```

Don't use `paste` and join the lines with `awk`

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[FNR]=$0;next} {printf("\"%s\",\"%s\"\n",a[FNR],$0)}' file1 file2
```

Edit: When you double quotes in your data, you must duplicate these quotes first. Something like

```
paste -d, <(sed 's/"/""/g; s/.*/"&"/' file1) <(sed 's/"/""/g; s/.*/"&"/' file2)
```

or

```
paste -d'\r' file1 file2 | sed -r 's/"/""/g; s/([^\r]*)\r(.*)/"\1","\2"/'
```

Comment: Iam able get comma in file,But the values which have double quotes(") are being displayed as example: before: a="a;b" after running the script it is coming like a=a;b"" for all values which have double quotes,Can you please suggest,Command used: paste-d, <(sed 's/.*/"&"/' file1) <(sed 's/.*/"&"/' file2)

Comment: This is an example why showing example input files is a good plan, I could have made a solution for the quotes without an edit.

Comment: Simply superb!!!Its working